# Reorder elements of HTML and change content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reorder in which some elements of web page are displayed. Following the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071701/change-div-order-with-jquery), I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        function reorder() {
            var grp = $(".myItems").children();
            var cnt = grp.length;

            var temp,x;
            for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                temp = grp[i];
                x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnt);
                grp[i] = grp[x];
                grp[x] = temp;
            }
            $(grp).remove();
            $(".myItems").append($(grp));
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="reorder();">
    <div class="myItems">
     <div class="item" title="Row 1">1</div>
     <div class="item" title="Row 2">2</div>
     <div class="item" title="Row 3">3</div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is that I also need to modify the content of the `<div>` tags depending on the order in which they appear. In this example, I need the row identifiers in the `title` tag to change.

For example, after refreshing, possible results would be:

```
    <div class="myItems">
     <div class="item" title="Row 1">2</div>
     <div class="item" title="Row 2">1</div>
     <div class="item" title="Row 3">3</div>
    </div>
```

or

```
    <div class="myItems">
     <div class="item" title="Row 1">3</div>
     <div class="item" title="Row 2">2</div>
     <div class="item" title="Row 3">1</div>
    </div>
```

Notice that the order of the titles remains the same while the displayed numbers change.

Comment: where is the problem? it works fine.

Comment: put your code to js fiddle and then inspect. the sequence of title is the same as the value showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before `$(grp).remove()`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i ++) {
    grp[i].title = "Row " + (i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over `grp` after you've randomised them and for each, reset attribute `title` to `'Row '+i`, where `i = index in array + 1`.
You can do this during the random step if you do

```
grp[i].setAttribute('title','Row '+(i+1));
grp[x].setAttribute('title','Row '+(x+1));
```

This results in calling `.setAttribute` many more times but requires one less loop.