# Randomize children elements on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to randomize the children elements of any `<div>`, `<ul>` on load with javascript. I am searching for the best approach to do it. Can some one help?

Suppose i have a `<ul>` with 5 `<li>` elements. On load i want the `<li>` elements to appear in random order.

Comment: can u be more specific ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomize a sequence of div elements with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533910/randomize-a-sequence-of-div-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quicky out of my head:

1. Remove all the items in the `<ul>` with [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
2. Store them in an array.
3. [Shuffle that array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array)
4. Insert elements in `<ul>` again.

Also take a look at this question: [randomize div elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533910/randomize-a-sequence-of-div-elements-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it (JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LNvqr/2/)

If you use jQuery and have HTML similar to this:

```
<div>
    <ul id="rndList">
        <li id="itemOne">one</li>
        <li id="itemTwo">two</li>
        <li id="itemThree">three</li>
        <li id="itemFour">four</li>
        <li id="itemFive">five</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Then you could simply use [.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove and store the array of the `<li>` elements.
Next, with a copy of the array, use `Math.random()` to generate a (pseudo)random integer between 0 and one less than the size of the array. Use this as the random index to be copied from the original (ordered) list in to the new (randomly-ordered) one.
Remove the randomly-chosen element from the original array on each iteration and choose a new random one until all elements have been re-inserted:

```
function shuffleList() {   
    var origList = $("#rndList li").detach();
    var newList = origList.clone();

    for (var i = 0; i < newList.length; i++) {
        //select a random index; the number range will decrease by 1 on each iteration
        var randomIndex = randomInt(newList.length - i);

        //place the randomly-chosen element into our copy and remove from the original:
        newList[i] = origList.splice(randomIndex, 1);

        //place the element back into into the HTML
        $("#rndList").append(newList[i]);
    }
}

function randomInt(maxNum) { //returns a random integer from 0 to maxNum-1
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with below code:

```
$(function () {
    var parent = $("#parent-container");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```