# How to randomly sort list items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, random, html-lists

I currently have this code that randomly sorts list items:

```
var $ul = $('#some-ul-id');
$('li', $ul).sort(function(){
   return ( Math.round( Math.random() ) - 0.5 )
}).appendTo($ul);
```

However, is there any better solution for that?

Answer (score 39):

Look at [this question and answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533910/randomize-a-sequence-of-div-elements-with-jquery#11766418). I like this solution via the user `gruppler`:

```
$.fn.randomize = function(selector){
    var $elems = selector ? $(this).find(selector) : $(this).children(),
        $parents = $elems.parent();

    $parents.each(function(){
        $(this).children(selector).sort(function(){
            return Math.round(Math.random()) - 0.5;
        // }). remove().appendTo(this); // 2014-05-24: Removed `random` but leaving for reference. See notes under 'ANOTHER EDIT'
        }).detach().appendTo(this);
    });

    return this;
};
```

**EDIT:** Usage instructions below.

To randomize all `<li>` elements within each '.member' `<div>`:

```
$('.member').randomize('li');
```

To randomize all children of each `<ul>`:

```
$('ul').randomize();
```

**ANOTHER EDIT:** [`akalata`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555415/how-to-randomly-sort-list-items/14555430#comment35262874_14555430) has let me know in the comments that `detach()` can be used instead of `remove()` with the main benefit being if any data or attached listeners are connected to an element and they are randomized, `detach()` will keep them in place. `remove()` would just toss the listeners out.

Comment: The issue you cite has been updated to use detach() instead of remove() -- just an FYI in case somebody else is wondering where their other attached behvaiors went!

Comment: You should never shuffle lists by sorting them with a random comparator. See http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/compare.html for a pretty visual explanation

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck to such questions I search on google and come across one code. I modify this code for my uses. I also include the shuffle the list after 15 seconds.

```
<script>
 // This code helps to shuffle the li ...
(function($){
       $.fn.shuffle = function() {
         var elements = this.get()
         var copy = [].concat(elements)
         var shuffled = []
         var placeholders = []
         // Shuffle the element array
         while (copy.length) {
           var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length)
           var element = copy.splice(rand,1)[0]
           shuffled.push(element)
         }

         // replace all elements with a plcaceholder
         for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
           var placeholder = document.createTextNode('')
           findAndReplace(elements[i], placeholder)
           placeholders.push(placeholder)
         }

         // replace the placeholders with the shuffled elements
         for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
           findAndReplace(placeholders[i], shuffled[i])
         }

         return $(shuffled)
       }

       function findAndReplace(find, replace) {
         find.parentNode.replaceChild(replace, find)
       }

       })(jQuery);

       // I am displying the 6 elements currently rest elements are hide.

       function listsort(){
       jQuery('.listify_widget_recent_listings ul.job_listings').each(function(index){
         jQuery(this).find('li').shuffle();
         jQuery(this).find('li').each(function(index){
           jQuery(this).show();
           if(index>=6){
             jQuery(this).hide();
           }
         });
       });
       }
       // first time call to function ...
       listsort();
       // calling the function after the 15seconds.. 
       window.setInterval(function(){
         listsort();
         /// call your function here 5 seconds.
       }, 15000);                 
</script>
```

Hope this solution helps....Have a great working time ..