# Shuffle jQuery selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to shuffle the order of a jQuery selection **without shuffle the elements in the DOM**.

I need to shuffle the selection to add a class to each element in random order, this is how my code should look:

```
$(".item").shuffle().each(function (i, element) {
    $(element).delay(i * 100).queue(function (next) {
        $(this).addClass("shown");
        next();
    });
});
```

Can someone help me finding the `shuffle()` function I need?

Comment: it looks like you are trying to shuffle the order of some list elemets. google search for 'suffle unordered list' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555415/jquery-how-to-random-sort-list-items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I borrowed the `Array.shuffle` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript), and made it into a jQuery plugin

```
$.fn.shuffle = function(){
    for(var j, x, i = this.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = this[--i], this[i] = this[j], this[j] = x);
    return this;
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vBp6/)

Comment: I don't think an array shuffle will do it, it looks like the shuffle will be done on html elements.

Comment: @superUntitled - and that's why I modified it to work on a jQuery collection

Answer (score 0):

```
$.fn.shuffle = function () {
    'use strict';
    var self = this,
        i,
        rnd,
        len = self.length - 1;
    for (i = len; i > 0; i -= 1) {
        rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * len) % i;
        [self[i], self[rnd]] = [self[rnd], self[i]];
    }
    return self;
}
```