# simultaneous functions javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code, it's supposed to toggle elements, following a repetitive patron, that will grow up randomly, my start function executes my runp() function at simultaneous, and it got all messy. i would need to wait until runp() finishes to continue executing. Thanks

```
function runp(patron){
  var x = 0;
  var intervalID = setInterval(function () {
     $("#container"+patron[x]).toggle(1).delay(1000).toggle(1).delay(1000);     

     if (++x === 20) {
         window.clearInterval(intervalID);
     }
  }, 2000);
}

function start(patron, patronl){    
  while (patron.length<20){
    patron.push(rand(1,4));
    runp(patron);
  }   
}
```

Comment: Please let us know what you intend your code to do.

Comment: What is purpose of calling `setInterval` inside `while` loop? `intervalID` does not appear to be global identifier? Are you trying to call `setInterval` twenty times in sequence?

Comment: They will never be simultaneous

Comment: I think you just need to call `runp(patron)` after the `while` loop is done. Otherwise, the interval will try to access `patron[x]` that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: the setInterval breaks, i needed the delay because i needed to finish the animation to continue. what i need now is to finish the setInterval to call another one

Comment: the problem is that i need to run runp everytime it adds a new element

Comment: I think you do not want interval...

Comment: and how i pause the function untill the toggles are finished?

Comment: _"and how i pause the function untill the toggles are finished?"_ Are you trying to toggle elements in sequence? Or, toggle a group of elements randomly?

Comment: thats exactly what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.queue()`

```
// alternatively pass randomly shuffled array of elements to `$.map()`
$({}).queue("toggle", $.map($("[id^=container]"), function(el) {
  return function(next) {
    return $(el).toggle(1).delay(1000).toggle(1).delay(1000)
           .promise().then(next)
  }
})).dequeue("toggle")
```

Comment: @Maximiliano Version 2 of linked plnkr randomly sorts elements where `id` begins with `container` randomly, before beginning animations, using approach described at [Randomize the divs that I append into another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029503/randomize-the-divs-that-i-append-into-another-one)