# How to generate random radio button positions?

Tags: php, html

I know my question title is not clear and I will explain here.

There is four radio buttons and its like examination test where every question have 4 answers. Problem is every question's should have random answer option.
 *the right answer will contain value=1.*

Q1 This is question 1?

```
<input type ="radio" value="1" />
<input type ="radio" value="2" />
<input type ="radio" value="3" />
<input type ="radio" value="4" />
```

Q2 This is question 2?

```
 <input type ="radio" value="2" />
    <input type ="radio" value="4" />
    <input type ="radio" value="1" />
    <input type ="radio" value="3" />
```

How can I generate random option?

I am using PHP and fetching options value from database.

Comment: depending on the db structure you could add `order by rand()` to each query. or randomise the data via php

Comment: Do you want a random option or a random order?

Comment: maybe checking out this post might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533910/randomize-a-sequence-of-div-elements-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

With PHP you can create an array with all the possible values and then suffle them:

```
$vals = [1, 2, 3, 4];
shuffle ($vals);
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($vals); $i++) : ?>
    <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $vals[$i] ?>" />
<?php endfor ?>
```

Every time you want new random values you can call `shuffle` again.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from your_table order by rand()
```

**E X A M P L E**

**Database:**

```
TABLE: question
id question
1  what is..
2  when did..
3  Which one..

TABLE: answer
id question_id answer_options  correct
1  1           answer 1        0
2  1           answer 2        1
3  1           answer 3        0
4  1           answer 4        0
```

**Query:**

```
Question loop STARTS

# Use the question_id to loop through the below
$query        = "SELECT * FROM answer where question_id='$question_id' order by rand()";
$qr           = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($qr) > 0)
{
$count = 2;
while ($res = mysqli_fetch_object($qr))
{
    if ($res->correct == 1)
    $value = 1;
    else
    $value = $count++;

    echo '<input type="radio" value="'.$value.'" /> '.$res->answer_options;
}
}

Question loop ENDS
```

Note: Didnt tested